# Замена json формата данных

Tags: json, php

Как известно формат json получил огромную популярность. На ряду с достоинством, он имеет и ряд недостатков. Одним из них является: передача большого текста с переносом строк.
Пример:

```
while(1);{"param1","extra long value
from sdfds"}
```

Как видите, я специально привел такой пример. Решение конечно же есть, сделать предварительную обработку параметров на сервере или на клиенте. Но меня это не устраивает.

**Вопрос**: Есть ли более продвинутая технология обмена данными? Критерием является экономичность трафика и простота в использовании(хотя про последнее молчу-код все обработает). В идеале хочется передавать данные клиенту без подготовки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой формат обмена данными - AMF. Формат был создан в рамках платформы flash, он бинарный, и имеет ряд преимуществ перед JSON и XML:

1. Компактность
2. Быстрая сериализация и десериализация

Почитать о нем можно здесь:

1. [Action Message Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format)
2. [Беглый обзор AMF с выводами](http://yzh44yzh.com/amf)
3. [AMF 3 Specification](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/1114283/amf3_spec_05_05_08.pdf)

Вообще выбор формата обмена данными всегда зависит от поставленной задачи, поэтому нельзя сказать, что AMF **всегда** будет эффективенее JSON или XML

Answer (score 2):

```
 php -r 'echo json_encode(array("a" => "multiline\r\ntext"));'

{"a":"multiline\r\ntext"}
```

как же так ? Что я делаю не правильно ?

Comment: Непонятно к чему вопрос. Но я не использую в своих проектах json_encode

Comment: На момент первого комента был другой текст! точно помню!

Answer (score 1):

> Непонятно к чему вопрос. Но я не использую в своих проектах json_encode

То, что вы не корректно формируете JSON строку, вовсе не означает, что это проблема в технологии. JSON строка не может содержать не экранированные управляющие символы.

[json.org](http://www.json.org/):

> ```
> string
>     ""
>     " chars "
> chars
>     char
>     char chars
> char
>     any-Unicode-character-except-"-or-\-or-control-character
>     \"
>     \\
>     \/
>     \b
>     \f
>     \n
>     \r
>     \t
>     \u four-hex-digits
> ```

Comment: А то, что я не хочу утруждать сервер перекодированием инфы. Хочу передавать ее через как можно меньшее количество посредников (json_encode - посредник). Верно подмечено, что это уже не будет верным форматом json. Хочу более выгодный вариант решения, нежели каждый раз ... Ориентир на создание мега highload проэкта, отсюда как можно меньше функций...

Comment: Так и надо было ставить вопрос соответствующим образом, что, мол, вас вас не устраивает размер/скорость JSON сериализаторов и вы ищете более быстрый/компактный аналог. А не то, что JSON не поддерживает перевод строк.

PS "Мега highload проэкты" требуют разработки гибкой и [масштабируемой][1] архитектуры, а не [экономии на спичках][2]. 

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C
  [2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_(computer_science)#When_to_optimize

Comment: Я вроде так и спросил)